# Extracting numbers from string in batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, batch-processing

I have file that is in format `Name $4.00` and I want to extract just numbers (everything after `$`), so I can comparate them later. How I can do that?

Comment: Is the string part of the file name or it written inside the file?Is it always in this format?

Comment: @npocmaka It is written inside the file. It's always in that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by @dekkard is for UNIX. You wanted a solution for CMD or BAT file. Your question is a bit simplistic so in the interest of keeping the answer simple I won't accommodate:

1. Characters following the number... that could be added if need be.
2. Comma in the number... could be accommodated if need be
3. $ in name/description field other than immediately preceding the number

You did not specify whether you wanted to retain the decimal point. Presumably you don't if your are going to do an integer compare later. Use one of these in BAT file.

If you don't want decimal point:

```
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$." %%a in (YourFile.txt) do echo(%%a%%b
```

Use this if you want to keep decimal point

```
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$" %%a in (YourFile.txt) do echo(%%a%%b
```

Use one of these from CMD line

```
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$." %a in (YourFile.txt) do echo(%a%b
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=$" %a in (YourFile.txt) do echo(%a%b
```

Comment: Great insight. The ```bash``` tag misled me completely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are separated by space(s), this should work:

```
sed 's/.* \+$\(.\+\)/\1/' your_input_file
```

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Because this a solution for ```bash``` as specified in your first tag.